# How to install coqide (or such) with brew

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I went into a lot of troubles getting coq installed on my Mac (Mavericks) and it actually didn't install coqide along…

Unfortunately 'brew options coq' has no results so I don't know how to install properly coqide.

If it's too complicated, it's fine, I'd welcome any alternate solution (like a sublime text plugin or such).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the [distributed binaries](http://coq.inria.fr/download)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work on os x mavericks (it appears to be a known bug), that is why I had to brew --devel to get a more recent version (on which the bug is fixed). That is why I'd like to get coqide separately (to keep something proper).

Answer (score 1):

The same bug (in the existing released binary) is reported here:

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3155

and in the comments a link to recent builds is given:

http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~pboutill/coq-night/v8.4/

I don't know about stability, but 8.4pl4 appears to be working on Mavericks. I was able to build/install following README instructions (might additionally require install of OCaml and other tools, which I happened to already have.) The associated coqide also appears to be working without trouble.

I am not a seasoned Coq user, so if there are any functionality or stability considerations in this non-published version, then they would be going far over my head.